# Visual Studio Cordova - can't deploy app

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with Cordova Tools. I have simple bootstrapped HTML5 app, and an iMac running the remotebuild agent.

I have an iPad connected to my Windows machine with VS, and I'm selecting Debug -> iOS -> Local Device

VS seems to successfully post the build request to the iMac, it builds successfully, but then VS output window repeats over and over that "build completed successfully".

I can't see how to install my app on the connected iPad - I've installed a provisioning profile, and have iTunes installed, but no idea what is supposed to happen next.

Comment: According to this instruction:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757056.aspx#iOSDevice

Building the app will start iTunes and the app will "automatically be added to the library". It doesn't for me.

Comment: Are you using Node.js v4.0 on your iMac? There's a known issue with that version, which sounds different from this, but I want to be sure.

Comment: I'm using 0.12.7, installed with Homebrew. My PC has 0.10.26 - I downgraded when I saw there might be problems with v4.0 and edge.

Comment: Just so I better understand what is meant to happen - presumably endlessly polling the build machine and returning "build completed successfully" is not expected behaviour? What ought I be seeing? Does the built package get returned to my PC - perhaps in the bld or bin folders? If it helps, the iOS folders in them are empty.

Comment: You're right that endless polling is not expected. After a build is successful, you should find the built .ipa file in a \bin\iOS\Debug folder on your PC. Though, like you say, you have an empty folder there. On your build Mac, with the remotebuild tool running, do you see any messages in the terminal window as the .ipa is built? Can you tell that the request makes it to the remotebuild service?

Answer (score 2):

Its a bug in visual studio 2015 and seems to effect ios developers running OSX Yosemite (Most reports were coming from that version)

there are 2 common problems with git integration in the transformation process(its likely that your project has created one during the transfer):

1. .git* (.gitignore and etc.) are located in wrong folder
2. .git* (.gitignore and etc.) are configured improperly

Solution:

1. move anything .git* to your root folder. i.e the folder with .sln file except the ones located in other platforms' (android, etc.) folder, they are probably located in the project folder(one level inside root project folder) or less likely, the www folder.
2. reconfigure your .git* files, since its not a git related question i'll try not to bother with details but an example visual studio .gitignore can be found
   [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) (it will most likely solve your problem alone)

Hope the answer was helpful, btw let me know whether the solution has fixed your problem, there are plenty of bugs in cordova development in V.S 2015 and your best bet is to wait for update 1 unfortunately.