# Visual Studio Cordova - The remote build client certificate is missing

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I've got a local iMac with the remotebuild agent, but get this error message when I try to run or debug on my PC:

```
The remote build client certificate is missing
```

As a test, I provisioned a remote mac with MacinCloud, and get the same error.

In both scenarios, I've run:

```
remotebuild resetServerCert
remotebuild generateClientCert
```

...on the remote machine, received the credentials, and added them to Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you try setting the credentials within 10 minutes of generating them? Just for kicks, does "non-secure" mode work? Try running the "remotebuild --secure false" and see if the connection from VS succeeds. You will have to change the settings in the VS (when you run in non-secure mode).

Comment: Non-secure seems to work. It gives me another issue, for which I've posted a different question, but it certainly connects to the remote machine. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573058/visual-studio-cordova-cant-deploy-app)

Comment: When I'm actually entering the remote config credentials in VS, it seems happy enough - i.e. if I had a wrong PIN, or remotebuild isn't running, I'd see an error message. But with the correct PIN, it goes through OK, then fails on build with the error above.

Comment: I tried this with a different PC and it worked. Same project, same version of VS, same version of Cordova Tools, but different versions of Windows. The PC it worked on is it, the one it didn't is 10. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: I reinstalled VS, uninstalled node, nvm and cleaned everything else I could find. It works now, but I'm afraid I can't tell anyone what fixed it. Perhaps I should delete this question?